# NodeJS User System

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am looking to create user auth system where they can register,login, reset password and more.

Are there any great modules / frameworks out there you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can you passport.js with the Express framework for authentication purpose.
Refer to this http://www.passportjs.org/.

Probably you will find much more tutorial related to this.